# Add a string to a copy command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to give a previously declared string that represents a path I want in a `copy` command.

Something like:

```
SET PATH_SOURCE = "C:\lala.txt"
copy PATH_SOURCE  "C:\folder\lala.txt"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
set "PATH_SOURCE=C:\lala.txt"
copy "%PATH_SOURCE%" "C:\folder\lala.txt"
```

Note that there must not be any spaces before or after the `=`. The `%` before and after the variable name make CMD expand the variable to the value you assigned before. The double quotes are a safeguard in case the path contains spaces.